# Placeholder text is not working with tinyMCE react

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE react

```
"tinymce": "^6.7.0",
"@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^4.3.0",
```

I am trying to add placeholder to the editor. and its supported form `v5.0.2`,

My init function

```
<Editor
    init={{
        height: 200,
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        toolbar_location : 'bottom',
        placeholder: "placeholder text",
        inline_styles : true,
        plugins: ['advlist', 'lists'],
        toolbar: 'bold italic underline | custom-link | bullist numlist',
        content_style: 'body { font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,Droid Sans,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif; font-size:14px }',
        skin: false,
        content_css: false,
        setup: this.initEditor,
    }}
    onInit={(evt, editor) => {
        this.editorRef.current = editor;
        this.controller.setReady()
    }}
    onEditorChange={this.onChangeEditor}
  />
```

However, it's not showing up in the editor. After inspecting, I can see it's adding the placeholder to the editor body.

[image]

But it's not showing up in the editor. What could be the reason for it not working?

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE has a specific configuration option for including a placeholder:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/editor-important-options/#placeholder

For example:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  placeholder: 'Type here...'
});
```

Per the TinyMCE 5.x docs this feature was first added in 5.2.0 so if you are running 5.0.x this is simply not available in the version of TinyMCE you are using and you would need to upgrade to at least 5.2.0.

Comment: This is not working, i already added the placeholder to the init function

Comment: If you are using 5.0.2 that configuration option is not valid (please see the second part of my response). You need to update to at least 5.2.0.